# Remove Commerce Payment Method Pane?

Tags: 7, commerce

So for my project there will only ever be one payment method with is Credit Card by Sage Pay.

Essentially I want to remove the pane where you select a payment method and 
set the payment method always as Sage Pay. I want to hide payment selection from the user.

This way after entering user details the user can go straight to the payment gateway redirection. How would I go about this?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a custom module with the following function:

```
function yourmodule_form_commerce_checkout_form_checkout_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
 // Do something here
}
```

You'll probably want to add a `dpm($form);` (assuming you have Devel installed) to get the exact item, but the array you'll probably want to target is:
`$form['commerce_payment']['payment_method']` by perhaps setting the `#access` to `FALSE` if you only have one choice. In other words, add the following:
`$form['commerce_payment']['payment_method']['#access'] = FALSE;`

Be sure to clear the cache after adding this function.

Comment: @slawrence10, can you comment what did/didn't work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Go to Administration >> Checkout settings (`admin/commerce/config/checkout`). Move the payment method pane to `Disabled` region and save setting.

[image: Payment inside disabled region]